# Creating a Flutter widget with two nested loops

Tags: flutter, widget, nested-loops, conditional-operator

I would like to create a widget in Flutter, which would look about as follows:

Text field group 1

[The first text field]

[The second text field]

Text field group 2

[The first text field]

[The second text field]

My code looks as follows:

```
class LoopWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  List textFieldLabels = ['The first text field', 'the second text field'];
    @override
    LoopWidget();
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
        for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
         for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    //The title should be here
         (j == 0) ? Text('Text field group ' + (i+1).toString()),
         Container(child: 
        TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: textFieldLabels[j],
                  )))]
    );
  }
}
```

However, this does not work. Is the ternary operator a correct way of doing this? If not what would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
class LoopWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  LoopWidget();
  final List textFieldLabels = [
    'The first text field',
    'the second text field'
  ];
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < textFieldLabels.length; i++) ...[
          Text('Text field group ${i+1}'),
          for(String labelText in textFieldLabels)
            TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: labelText,
            ),
          ),
         
        ],
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I used a combination of `for loop` and `for-in loop`

Comment: Thank you, this works indeed! May I ask, what are those three dots right after the definition (or specifications) of the first for loop?

Comment: its called spread operator, for more info please check https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-using-triple-dot-spread-operator-examples

Answer (score 0):

**Your Code Modifed:**

```
class LoopWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  LoopWidget();
  int i;
  int j;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: listOfWidgets(),
    );
  }
  List textFieldLabels = ['The first text field', 'the second text field'];
  List<Widget> listOfWidgets() {
    List<Widget> list = new List();
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        if (j == 0) {
          list.add(
            new Text('Text field group ' + (i + 1).toString()),
          );
        }
        list.add(
          new Container(
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: textFieldLabels[j],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Correct me, if I am wrong, byt the function listOfWidgets has no return statement and nothing is therefore returned.

Comment: @Aku-Ville Lehtimäki: No, it doesn't require a return statement.